# Regex - need to find content of exact pattern and around it

Tags: java, regex

I have this following string:

```
"xxxx_result=0,oper,oper,oper,result=[{field1:1,field1:2,field1:3}]"
```

I need to find the string which is `result=[{field1:1,field1:2,field1:3}]`

What I made so far is like this:

```
String s = "xxxx_result=0,oper,oper,oper,result=[{field1:1,field1:2,field1:3}]";
String ps = "result=(.*)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

But it didn't succeed to get the `result` which has a value of JSON, how can I manage to get it?

Comment: Is the result always in the same place? After 4 commas, with no trailing data? If so, it would be easier just to find the 4th comma and return the following substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
String ps = "(result=([\\D.*).*)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex :

```
.*(result=\[\{[^}]*\}\])
```

In java :

```
String ps = ".*(result=\\[\\{[^}]*\\}\\])";
String s = "xxxx_result=0,oper,oper,oper,result=[{field1:1,field1:2,field1:3}]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // returns value of s
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // returns result=[{field1:1,field1:2,field1:3}]

}
```

Check the regex here https://regex101.com/r/kT1vP9/1

Answer (score 0):

Just change your pattern to

```
String ps = ",result=(.*?])";
```

I have added the `,` to make sure you get the correct `result` match, and then it matches everything up until and including the first encountered `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, all you need is a word boundary:

```
String ps = "\\bresult=(.*)";
```

This will avoid matching in `result=` part in `xxxx_result=0` part.

Another possibility is to use a lookbehind to make sure comma comes before `result=`:

```
String ps = "(?<=,)result=(.*)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to get `result=[{field1:1,field1:2,field1:3}]` from the `String`:

```
String s = "xxxx_result=0,oper,oper,oper,result=[{field1:1,field1:2,field1:3}]";
```

you could use a regular expression that looks for `result={[`, then not `}` or `]`, least amount of times as possible `*?`, followed by `}]`.

```
String ps = "(result=\\[\\{[^\\]\\}]*?\\}\\])";
```